# How to change the DataSource on a GridView (C#, ASP.Net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, datasource

I was wondering if any of you all knew how to change the DataSource on a gridview from the code behind. I have a GridView (gdvCars), and a dropdownlist that has all of the models listed. When a model is selected, the user presses a button. When the button is pressed, it will switch data sources according to what was selected. What I am having trouble with, is figuring out the correct syntax to switch the dataSource that my GridView is using. How do you Unbind the first dataSource, and switch to a new one?

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example:

In your page:

```
<asp:DropDownList id="drp"
                  runat="server">
     <asp:ListItem Value="GridViewDataSource1">Name 1</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="GridViewDataSource2">Name 2</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="GridViewDataSource3">Name 3</asp:ListItem>         
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:sqldatasource id="GridViewDataSource1" selectcommand="SELECT .. FROM .. " connectionstring="..." runat="server"/>
<asp:sqldatasource id="GridViewDataSource2" selectcommand="SELECT .. FROM .. " connectionstring="..." runat="server"/>
<asp:sqldatasource id="GridViewDataSource3" selectcommand="SELECT .. FROM .. " connectionstring="..." runat="server"/>
```

In code behind:

```
void button_click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string SourceName = drp.SelectedValue;
    gdvCars.DataSourceID = SourceName;
    gdvCars.DataBind();
}
```